# Trouble creating Gluon Application - Exception in Plugin Error

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, mobile, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am trying to use Gluon to create a mobile application. I have followed the steps exactly on http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.4.1/#intellij-plugin to use Gluon with IntelliJ. I keep getting this error:

[image]

Also IDEA doesn't detect that I am trying to import a Gradle Project.

When it is opened the project looks like this:

[image]

The stack trace is below:

[image: Stacktrace]

Also the gluon version is the latest one.

Comment: Just as the dialog says, report a bug!

Comment: Which is the plugin version? Can you post also the exception stacktrace, if any, shown under Details?

Comment: I just put the stacktrace in the question. The version is the latest one released on November 3rd.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I've filed an issue on this. A fix should be available soon.

Comment: The Gluon plugin version 2.6.1 is already available for IntelliJ, you can check for updates and install it to solve the issue.